# How does argument dependent lookup find declarations after the search point?

Tags: c++, lookup, argument-dependent-lookup

```
struct A {
    void g(A a) {
        f(a);
        }
    friend void f(A a);
    };
void f(A a) { }
int main() {
    A a;
    a.g(a);
}
```

The code above compiles and run without problems, but I didn't get how the lookup for `f(a)` occurs. Initially will occur a unqualified name lookup in the class and its parent scope, that is the global scope. Since the `friend f` is not a member and there is no `using-directive` I presume that unqualified name lookup will find nothing. So *Argument dependent lookup* takes place. The C++ draft 2021(N4901)(chapter 6.5.4  [basic.lookup.argdep]
) quotes:

> Argument-dependent lookup finds all declarations of functions and
> function templates that (4.1) — are found by a search of any
> associated namespace, or (4.2) — are declared as a friend (11.8.4) of
> any class with a reachable definition in the set of associated
> entities, or (4.3) — are exported, are attached to a named module M
> (10.2), do not appear in the translation unit containing the point of
> the lookup, and have the same innermost enclosing non-inline namespace
> scope as a declaration of an associated entity attached to M (6.6).

The friend declaration looks that fits in the 4.2, but what about the global scope `void f(A a){}`? It looks it doesn't fit in 4.1(since it doesn't preeced the search point), neither in 4.2 nor in 4.3. How is the defining function found?

Comment: It's called 2-phase lookup, and occurs at POI (point of instantiation)

Comment: @sehe Two-phase lookup is about dependent names in templates. There are no templates in this example, and no instantiation.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Oh I had not looked at any sample code. And assumed it was the classical source of confusion. My bad. I'll be back in my [tag:boost] corner :)

Answer (score 3):

> **[basic.scope.class]/1** The potential scope of a name declared in a class consists not only of the declarative region following the name’s point of declaration, but also of all function bodies ... in that class.

Thus, the name `f` introduced by the `friend` declaration is visible within the body of `g`, and is found by unqualified lookup.

Comment: But a friend declaration is not a member right? A unqualified lookup performs a search in the class scope, but it only find members

Comment: No, it will find names declared in class scope, whether those of class members or otherwise. In particular, `friend` declaration is a way to declare a non-member in class scope (possibly the only way; I can't think of another off the top).

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/class.member.lookup#2 I am a little confused. From the link I understood that a search in a scope of a class only find members.

Comment: This text doesn't exist in C++17 nor C++20. I'm not sure how it works in the latest draft.